# Submersions and transversality in terms of orthogonality and factorization systems?

Tags: differential-geometry, category-theory, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Are the notions of submersion and transversal maps somehow a special case of the categorical notion of orthogonal morphisms and factorization systems?

Comment: Is there a reason you expect them to be?

Comment: @EricWofsey the fact submersions are transversal to all other maps into the same manifold just felt related...